# Calculate file size of file in pre-request script in postman

Tags: javascript, postman, filesize, newman, postman-pre-request-script

How to calculate the file size of a file included in a pre-request script in postman ?
(using JS or node js )

I tried to use **fs** module but *fs.statSync is not a function* is the error i get

Any other workarounds for this?